# JavaScript string to Unicode (Hex)

Tags: javascript, strings, array, converting, unicode

This set of questions are related to a project I've published for converting characters, or strings, to Hex based Unicode; eg...

```
toUnicode.fromCharacter('');
//> 1f34d

toUnicode.fromString('Spam!', '0x');
//> ['0x53', '0x70', '0x61', '0x6d', '0x21']
```

### Questions

- Are there any mistakes, such as unaccounted for edge-cases?
- Have I missed any test cases?
- Any suggestions on making the code more readable and/or easier to extend?
- Are there any features that are wanted?

---

### Setup and Usage

The [Source code](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/to-unicode) is maintained on GitHub and may be cloned via the following commands. A [Live demo](https://javascript-utilities.github.io/to-unicode/index.html) is hosted online, thanks to GitHub Pages.

```bsh
mkdir -vp ~/git/hub/javascript-utilities
cd ~/git/hub/javascript-utilities
git clone git@github.com:javascript-utilities/to-unicode.git
```

The build target is ECMAScript version 6, and so far both manual tests and automated JestJS tests show that the `toUnicode` methods function as intended; for both Browser and NodeJS environments.

**Example NodeJS Usage**

```
const toUnicode = require('./to-unicode.js');

var panda_code = toUnicode.fromCharacter('');

console.log(panda_code);
//> '1f43c'
```

---

### Source Code

I am concerned with improving the [JavaScript](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/to-unicode/blob/main/to-unicode.js), and [TypeScript](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/to-unicode/blob/main/ts/to-unicode.ts); ie. HTML is intended to be simple and functional.

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Namespace for static methods that convert characters and strings to Unicode
 */
class toUnicode {
    /**
     * Converts character to Hex Unicode
     * @param {string} character
     * @return {string}
     * @author S0AndS0
     * @copyright AGPL-3.0
     * @example
     * toUnicode.fromCharacter('');
     * //> "1f43c"
     */
    static fromCharacter(character) {
        return character.codePointAt(undefined).toString(16);
    }

    /**
     * Converts string to character array of Unicode(s)
     * @param {string} characters
     * @return {string[]}
     * @author S0AndS0
     * @copyright AGPL-3.0
     * @example
     * toUnicode.fromString(' ');
     * //> [ '1f389', '20', '1f44b' ]
     */
    static fromString(characters, prefix = '') {
        return [...characters].reduce((accumulator, character) => {
            const unicode = toUnicode.fromCharacter(character);
            accumulator.push(`${prefix}${unicode}`);
            return accumulator;
        }, []);
    }
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = toUnicode;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>toUnicode Usage Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modules/to-unicode.js" differ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" differ>
      const text_input__callback = (_event) => {
        const client_input = document.getElementById('client__text--input').value;
        const client_prefix = document.getElementById('client__text--prefix').value;

        const output_element = document.getElementById('client__text--output');

        const unicode_list = toUnicode.fromString(client_input, client_prefix);
        console.log(unicode_list);
        output_element.innerText = unicode_list.join('\n');
      };


      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const client_text_input = document.getElementById('client__text--input');
        const client_text_prefix = document.getElementById('client__text--prefix');

        client_text_input.addEventListener('input', text_input__callback);
        client_text_prefix.addEventListener('input', text_input__callback);
      });
    </script>
  </head>


  <body>
    <span>Prefix: </span>
    <input type="text" id="client__text--prefix" value="0x">

    <br>

    <span>Input: </span>
    <input type="text" id="client__text--input" value="">

    <pre id="client__text--output"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### JestJS Tests

For completeness here are the [JestJS](https://github.com/javascript-utilities/to-unicode/blob/main/__tests__/tests-to-unicode.js) tests.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Tests modules within `to-unicode.js` script
 * @author S0AndS0
 * @copyright AGPL-3.0
 */
class toUnicode_Test {
    constructor(min_code_point = 161, max_code_point = 1114111) {
        this.toUnicode = require('../to-unicode.js');
        this.min_code_point = min_code_point;
        this.max_code_point = max_code_point;
    }

    randomCodePoint() {
        return Math.random() * (this.max_code_point - this.min_code_point + 1) + this.min_code_point | 0;
    }

    runTests() {
        this.testInvariance();
    }

    /**
     * Tests if `fromCharacter()` and `fromString()` functions are reversible.
     */
    testInvariance() {
        const character_code_list = Array(99).fill(0).map((_) => {
            return this.randomCodePoint();
        });

        let unicode_list = [];
        let characters_string = '';

        test('Is `fromCharacter()` reversible?', () => {
            character_code_list.forEach((code_point) => {
                const character = String.fromCodePoint(code_point);
                const unicode = this.toUnicode.fromCharacter(character);
                const decimal = Number(`0x${unicode}`);
                expect(decimal).toEqual(code_point);
                unicode_list.push(unicode);
                characters_string += character;
            });
        });

        test('Is `fromString()` reversible?', () => {
            expect(this.toUnicode.fromString(characters_string)).toStrictEqual(unicode_list);
        });
    }
}

const test_toUnicode = new toUnicode_Test();
test_toUnicode.runTests();
```

Answer (score 7):

This is regarding the edge-cases and test cases mentioned in the question:

```
[...characters] // or Array.from(characters)
```

handles splitting the characters of string to an array in most of the cases. It is better than `characters.split("")` because it handles surrogate pairs pretty well.

```js
console.log( "".length ) // 2
console.log( [...""] )
console.log( "".split("") )
```

What if you input something like ‍‍‍? You get

```
0x1f468
0x200d
0x1f469
0x200d
0x1f467
0x200d
0x1f466
```

and not a single hex as output like before. Because, there are hundreds of *emoji sequences* which are combinations of multiple emojis but display as a single emoji. They are joined with a [Zero Width Joiner (U+200D)](https://codepoints.net/U+200d) character. When you use `[...]` on them, they are split into an array of individual emojis and joiner characters.

```js
console.log("️‍️".length) // 7
console.log(Array.from("️‍️"))

console.log("‍‍‍".length) // 11
console.log(Array.from("‍‍‍"))
```

Similarly, many languages create a grapheme or a symbol with [combining marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). They look like distinctive units of writing, but are made up of multiple unicode points.

The below strings are not the same. The first string has `á` but the second string is `a` and a combining mark [U+0301](https://codepoints.net/U+0301)

```js
const a = "álgebra",
      b = "álgebra"

console.log(a === b) // false
console.log(a.length, b.length)
console.log([...a].join(" , "))
console.log([...b].join(" , "))

console.log([..."हिन्दी"].join(" , ")) // Devanagari script
```

[`ि`](https://codepoints.net/U+093F) is a vowel sound and isn't used on it's own. It needs to be combined to with a consonant like `ह`(Ha) to get `हि` (He)

You can create big strings using multiple combining marks while the string looks like it has 6 distinct characters:

```js
const a = 'Z͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙̤̞͉͚̯̞̠͍A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢L̠ͨͧͩ͘G̴̻͈͍͔̹̑͗̎̅͛́Ǫ̵̹̻̝̳͂̌̌͘!͖̬̰̙̗̿̋ͥͥ̂ͣ̐́́͜͞'

console.log(a.length) // 75
console.log(Array.from(a))
```

The scenarios mentioned are not issues per se. You are basically converting the string to corresponding unicode hex. But, each grapheme or a symbol doesn't necessarily correspond to a single hex in the output. You can keep these in mind or add them to your edge cases / test cases.

Some further reading:

- [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)
- [What every JavaScript developer should know about Unicode](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/)
- [Full Emoji List, v13.0](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) (You can see the Code column to know if emojis are created from multiple emojis)
- [Emoji Zero Width Joiner ZWJ Sequence](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequence/)

---

Also, `codePointAt` takes a number as a parameter.

```
return character.codePointAt(undefined).toString(16)
```

is same as

```
return character.codePointAt().toString(16)
```

Both of these work because if the argument is `undefined`, it defaults to `0`. It's better to pass `0` explicitly as it is easily understandable. It wasn't clear why you were passing `undefined` initially.

```
return character.codePointAt(0).toString(16)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!... Passing `undefined` to `codePointAt` was done to prevent TypeScript from complaining, but I'll certainly consider switching to `0` as that seems to be less confusing for readers (myself included)... As for _`Array.from(_string_)`_ vs. _`[..._string_]`_, so far tests seem to produce equivalent output, and last I read the _spread_ syntax was the _short-hand_ way of avoiding issues with _`String.split("")`_ doing unkind things to non-ASCII strings.

Comment: @S0AndS0 sorry, I wan't clear in the answer. `Array.from()` and `[...]` are equivalent for a string input. They both use the [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) property of the string to create an array.